# Is it possible to have Flutter image_picker return two of the same image but with different quality?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-packages, flutter-image

Flutter [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) package allows one to select the quality of an image very easily and the re-sizing works really quickly:

```
XFile? pickedImage = await _picker.pickImage(
                                      imageQuality: 80,
                                      source: ImageSource.gallery);
```

I am looking for a best way to have the picked image be in a original size and smaller size for a thumbnail.

I have tried packages like [image_compression_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/image_compression_flutter) but at least for web it seemed very slow, whereas as image_picker works very fast regardless of the quality setting (0-100).

Is there a good way to to use image_picker to do this?

The goal would be that the user picks one image but then there would be two files - pickedImage (imageQuality:80) and pickedImageThumb (imageQuality:10). Right now of course this code below does not work as it creates two instances of picking an image. Is there a way to do this without having the user pick the same image twice?

```
XFile? pickedImage = await _picker.pickImage(
                                      imageQuality: 80,
                                      source: ImageSource.gallery);

 XFile? pickedImageThumb = await _picker.pickImage(
                                      imageQuality: 10,
                                      source: ImageSource.gallery);
```

If this does not work, is it possible to somehow use the same method image_picker uses in the background to do the compression as a stand alone function that would take pickedImage and resize it?

What is the main reason image_picker can do the compression so quickly compared to other packages and methods?

Answer (score 2):

I think there is not a way to return same image with different qualities because of this i advice you that get picked image using image_picker and then resize the same image with different quality . You can use this library (flutter_native_image: ^0.0.6+1) to resize image

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to make it work for web, iOS and Android.
The solution ended up being re-using the methods that the [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) package uses.

So what you can do is get an image from image picker that will be high quality/large image. Then use that as input to the following functions:

```
XFile? mainImage;
XFile? imageThumbnail;

void pickImage() async {
     XFile? pickedImage;
// this maybe gallery or camera
    pickedImage = await _picker.pickImage(imageQuality: 80, source: ImageSource.gallery,
        maxWidth: 1600,
        maxHeight: 1600);

    if (pickedImage != null) {

      mainImage = pickedImage;

      imageThumbnail = await resizeImageIfNeeded(file: pickedImage,imageQuality: 50,
          maxHeight: 250,
          maxWidth: 250 );

  }


Future<XFile> resizeImageIfNeeded(
    {required XFile file,
      double? maxWidth,
      double? maxHeight,
      int? imageQuality}) async {


  if (!imageResizeNeeded(maxWidth, maxHeight, imageQuality) ||
      file.mimeType == 'image/gif') {
    // Implement maxWidth and maxHeight for image/gif
    return file;
  }
  try {

    final html.ImageElement imageElement = await loadImage(file.path);

    final html.CanvasElement canvas =
    resizeImageElement(imageElement, maxWidth, maxHeight);
    final XFile resizedImage =
    await writeCanvasToFile(file, canvas, imageQuality);
    // html.Url.revokeObjectUrl(file.path);

    return resizedImage;
  } catch (e) {


    return file;
  }
}



/// function that loads the blobUrl into an imageElement
Future<html.ImageElement> loadImage(String blobUrl) {

  final Completer<html.ImageElement> imageLoadCompleter =
  Completer<html.ImageElement>();

  final html.ImageElement imageElement = html.ImageElement();

  imageElement.src = blobUrl;


  if (defaultTargetPlatform.name == "iOS" || defaultTargetPlatform.name == "android") {

    imageLoadCompleter.complete(imageElement);
  }


  imageElement.onLoad.listen((html.Event event) {
    imageLoadCompleter.complete(imageElement);

    //return imageLoadCompleter.future;
  });
  imageElement.onError.listen((html.Event event) {
    const String exception = 'Error while loading image.';
    imageElement.remove();
    imageLoadCompleter.completeError(exception);
  });
  return imageLoadCompleter.future;
}

/// Draws image to a canvas while resizing the image to fit the [maxWidth],[maxHeight] constraints
html.CanvasElement resizeImageElement(
    html.ImageElement source, double? maxWidth, double? maxHeight) {
  final Size newImageSize = calculateSizeOfDownScaledImage(
      Size(source.width!.toDouble(), source.height!.toDouble()),
      maxWidth,
      maxHeight);
  final html.CanvasElement canvas = html.CanvasElement();
  canvas.width = newImageSize.width.toInt();
  canvas.height = newImageSize.height.toInt();
  final html.CanvasRenderingContext2D context = canvas.context2D;
  if (maxHeight == null && maxWidth == null) {
    context.drawImage(source, 0, 0);
  } else {
    context.drawImageScaled(source, 0, 0, canvas.width!, canvas.height!);
  }
  return canvas;
}

/// function that converts a canvas element to Xfile
/// [imageQuality] is only supported for jpeg and webp images.
Future<XFile> writeCanvasToFile(
    XFile originalFile, html.CanvasElement canvas, int? imageQuality) async {
  final double calculatedImageQuality =
      (min(imageQuality ?? 100, 100)) / 100.0;
  final html.Blob blob =
  await canvas.toBlob(originalFile.mimeType!, calculatedImageQuality);

 

  return XFile(
      html.Url.createObjectUrlFromBlob(blob),
      mimeType: originalFile.mimeType,
      name: 'scaled_${originalFile.name}',
      lastModified: DateTime.now(),
      length: blob.size);
}
```

What you end up is once the user picks one image, you get one large image and one thumbnail image. It seems to work quite fast and so far no issues.

Answer (score 0):

While I was trying to pick image from Flutter web I had some difficulties. Firstly,there was no XFile type, so picking from web required to use packages. However, those packages had were too slow at compressing images. I opened a new issue [here](https://github.com/alann-maulana/image_compression_flutter/issues/2), then I found workaround, which is commented there. I'm still waiting for the soulution of the issue to be able to compress web image.

If you want to resize an image you should sacrifice web support. But if you want web support you should resize the image on your server.